# How to use csv.DictReader

Tags: python, csv

I am doing a program for a class, and our teacher gave us the csv.DictReader function to use, without explaining it.  It is just part of a larger program.  I am trying to read a spreadsheet of weather data.  It has several columns named TemperatureF, VisibilityMPH, etc.. I need to read in one column of the spreadsheet and put its values as a list, into a dictionary with the key being the column name.   I did this, however when I try to loop thru and do it for a second column, my list doesn't fill up.  Here is my code and output.

```
import csv

def read_file(filename, col_list):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)

        final_dict = {}
        x = 0
        while x < len(col_list):

            print 'X IS ' + str(x)
            this_list = []

            print 'list before adding stuff: ' #test

            print this_list   #test

            for row in reader:
                this_list.append([row[col_list[x]]])

            print 'list after adding stuff' #test

            print this_list   #test

            final_dict[col_list[x]] = this_list

            x += 1
        print final_dict

    def main():
        read_file('weather.csv', ['VisibilityMPH', 'TemperatureF'])


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        main()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Can you please paste the _text_ of the output into your question?

Comment: This program, as posted, doesn't read anything.

Comment: @qxz, i don't know how to copy the cmd line output

Comment: @ScottHunter it does the first time thru the loop, as shown in output

Comment: Take a look at the snippet in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#csv.DictReader). You have to iterate your reader object in order to access the properties of each line.

Comment: Not as posted, it doesn't.  At least not in python 2.7.

Comment: Either your indentation is wrong, or this code is never going to work. The `with` block for the file that `csv.DictReader` wraps (as currently shown) ends after creating the `reader` object. But the `reader` object has a live dependency on that open file, and if it's closed, you can't read anything from `reader`; the loop that tries to iterate it would die with `ValueError: I/O operation on closed file.` Since you claim to have output, that means the code you've posted does not match the code you're running. Please fix the indentation.

Comment: Believe i fixed the indentation.  Had to put 4 spaces before every line to indicate to this editor that its code? Maybe there's an easier way to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you probably want is this:

```
import csv

def read_file(filename, col_list):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)

        final_dict = {}
        x = 0

        while x < len(col_list):

            print 'X IS ' + str(x)
            this_list = []

            print 'list before adding stuff: ' #test

            print this_list   #test

            for row in reader:
                this_list.append([row[col_list[x]]])

            print 'list after adding stuff' #test

            print this_list   #test

            final_dict[col_list[x]] = this_list

            x += 1

        print final_dict

def main():
    read_file('weather.csv', ['VisibilityMPH', 'TemperatureF'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Notice your while block has an incorrect indentation. But the code snippet can actually be improved.

```
import csv

def read_file(filename, col_list):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f:
        reader = csv.DictReader(f)

        final_dict = { col_name: [] for col_name in col_list }

        for row in reader:
            for col_name in col_list:
                final_dict[col_name].append(row[col_name])

        print final_dict

def main():
    read_file('weather.csv', ['VisibilityMPH', 'TemperatureF'])


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```